# Lenovo Legion PrtSc key mapped to Win Super + Shift + S instead of Printscreen

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

I use Ubuntu 23.04 on a Legion slim 7i laptop and would like to keep <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> mapped to what it's named after `Printscreen`. I discovered through keyboard shortcuts that when I press <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, the key combo that appears is actually <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> which is windows' snip tool shortcut. I'd like to get rid of it if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind screenshot keys from the terminal:

- Set <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key to directly capture full-screen without interaction:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings screenshot ["'Print'"]
```

- Re-bind new screenshot UI to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd> (change the shortcut as you prefer):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screenshot-ui ["'<Shift>Print'"]
```

- To restore the shortcut keys to default, run commands:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.keybindings screenshot
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.keybindings show-screenshot-ui
```

Comment: What left me concerned is gnome keyboard-shortcuts interpreting PrtSc as super+shift+s. Would that not interfere with the keybinds that you've laid out in your answer?

Comment: Try it, but do both lines. `show-screenshot-ui` should overwrite the "Super+Shift+S" action you are worried about.